# Python: Build Binary Tree with Pre and Inorder

Tags: python, recursion, tree, tree-traversal

I need help completing the recursive part of my function. The function is supposed to use my ListBinaryTree Class to help reconstruct a tree given its inorder and preorder traversal in string format: eg.

```
preorder = '1234567'
inorder = '3241657' 

def build_tree(inorder, preorder):
    head = preorder[0]
    print(head)
    head_pos = inorder.index(head)
    print(head_pos)
    left_in = inorder[:head_pos]
    print(left_in)
    right_in = inorder[(head_pos+1):]
    print(right_in)
    left_pre = preorder[1:-len(right_in)]
    print(left_pre)
    right_pre = preorder[-len(right_in):]
    print(right_pre)
```

Which finds the important values in the preorder and inorder traversals and splits the tree up to determine which numbers are for the left side and right side of the tree.

An example of its input and output is:

```
build_tree('3241657', '1234567')
```

.

```
1
3
324
657
234
567
```

My class that I use to create the tree is as follows:

```
class ListBinaryTree:
"""A binary tree class with nodes as lists."""
DATA = 0    # just some constants for readability
LEFT = 1
RIGHT = 2   

def __init__(self, root_value, left=None, right=None):
    """Create a binary tree with a given root value
    left, right the left, right subtrees        
    """ 
    self.node = [root_value, left, right]

def create_tree(self, a_list):
    return ListBinaryTree(a_list[0], a_list[1], a_list[2])

def insert_value_left(self, value):
    """Inserts value to the left of this node.
    Pushes any existing left subtree down as the left child of the new node.
    """
    self.node[self.LEFT] = ListBinaryTree(value, self.node[self.LEFT], None)

def insert_value_right(self, value):
    """Inserts value to the right of this node.
    Pushes any existing left subtree down as the left child of the new node.
    """      
    self.node[self.RIGHT] = ListBinaryTree(value, None, self.node[self.RIGHT])

def insert_tree_left(self, tree):
    """Inserts new left subtree of current node"""
    self.node[self.LEFT] = tree

def insert_tree_right(self, tree):
    """Inserts new left subtree of current node"""
    self.node[self.RIGHT] = tree

def set_value(self, new_value):
    """Sets the value of the node."""
    self.node[self.DATA] = new_value

def get_value(self):
    """Gets the value of the node."""
    return self.node[self.DATA]

def get_left_subtree(self):
    """Gets the left subtree of the node."""
    return self.node[self.LEFT]

def get_right_subtree(self):
    """Gets the right subtree of the node."""
    return self.node[self.RIGHT]

def __str__(self):
    return '['+str(self.node[self.DATA])+', '+str(self.node[self.LEFT])+', '+\
 str(self.node[self.RIGHT])+']'
```

For the recursive part of the function I tried doing something like:

```
my_tree= ListBinaryTree(head)
while my_tree.get_value() != None:
        left_tree = build_tree(left_in, left_pre)
        right_tree = build_tree(right_in, right_pre)
        my_tree.insert_value_left(left_tree)
        my_tree.insert_value_right(right_tree)
    print (my_tree)
```

But it returns an "index out of range" error.

Also for something like:

```
def build_tree(inorder, preorder):
    head = preorder[0]
    head_pos = inorder.index(head)
    left_in = inorder[:head_pos]
    right_in = inorder[(head_pos+1):]
    left_pre = preorder[1:-len(right_in)]
    right_pre = preorder[-len(right_in):]
    if left_in:
        left_tree = build_tree(left_in, left_pre)
    else:
        left_tree = None
    if right_in:
        right_tree = build_tree(right_in, right_pre)
    else:
        right_tree = None
    my_tree =  ListBinaryTree(head, left_tree, right_tree)
    print(my_tree)
```

input

```
build_tree('3241657', '1234567')
```

returns

```
[3, None, None]
[4, None, None]
[2, None, None]
[6, None, None]
[7, None, None]
[5, None, None]
[1, None, None]
```

Can anyone please help me with the recursive part?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making the recursive part much harder than necessary.

```
if left_in:
    left_tree = build_tree(left_in, left_pre)
else:
    left_tree = None

if right_in:
    right_tree = build_tree(right_in, right_pre)
else:
    right_tree = None

return ListBinaryTree(head, left_tree, right_tree)
```

You could perhaps simplify it even further by moving the checks for empty sequences up to the top of the function (e.g. `if not inorder: return None`) so it only needs to appear once.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work with my particular BinaryTree class?

Comment: If I return instead of print it comes up with: <__main__.ListBinaryTree object at 0x02EF72B0>. Do i need to write a return method for my class?

Comment: That's the `repr` of the Tree. If you want to see the `str`, you need to call `print` on the return value. Making `build_tree` print instead of returning will break the recursion

Comment: How would I call print on the return value in this case? I have been trying a few ways but none seem to work.

Comment: First turn the `print` back into `return`. Without the return it will not work, because you'll get `None` from the recursive calls instead of a subtree. Then use `print(build_tree('3241657', '1234567'))` at the top level.

Comment: I did not know print cancels a recursion. Thank you. I will have to read up more about recursion.

Comment: `print` doesn't cancel anything, but putting it in *in place of* `return` does break things. It's the removal of the return that's the problem. You can leave the `print` statement in if you want, for debugging, for instance (but it won't be very pretty). And you need to thing about what your function is supposed to be doing. `build_tree` should be building a tree, not printing one.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could alter my code so that the function works with trees that have repeated values? eg. (1,1,2,3,4)

Comment: I'm not sure you can. Such a sequence in the pre-order or in-order traversal may be ambiguous (it could describe multiple different trees, since you can't tell which `1` is which).